Apache shows 'packet length too long' and 'wrong version number' when using SSL
On a new VPS I installed Ubuntu 24.04 server and installed PHP and Apache. I kept the freshly installed default configuration and I added ssl, using the standard provided ssl config /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf.
I expected a certificatie error which I could bypass in the browser, but I got this:
https://myvpsurl:
Firefox says: Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG and Brave something similar.
Then I curl'd it:
curl -I https://myvpsurl
curl: (35) OpenSSL/3.3.0: error:0A0000C6:SSL routines::packet length too long

Or with OpenSSL:
openssl s_client -connect myvpsurl:443 
CONNECTED(00000003)
8515619840:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 293 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---

The certificate messages are obvious as I have not registered the domains yet (Letsencrypt), so that is not the issue.
There was OpenSSL 3.0.14 installed which I upgraded to 3.3.0, but to no avail. Wrong version number ???
root@ubuntu:/root# apache2 -M
Here the installed modules:
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
root@ubuntu:/root# 

On another server (my Macbook Pro) running Apache 2.4.59 under Homebrew runs OpenSSL 3.3.0 as well and SSL requests run normally.
What is the issue here ?

Sounds like your server is using HTTP only - have you set your site up to use HTTPS? SSLEngine On ?

That is defined in the section <VirtualHost *:443> of /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf.

That did the trick.
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf was not included, I symlinked it to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf, kicked Apache and it worked (obviously with a certificate warning). Weird, because before port 443 was already open, despite the ssl conf was not loaded.

Thanks to @garethTheRed it is fixed, I had only enabled mod_ssl in Apache config, but the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf was not symlinked to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf. Weird as when doing a port scan or netstat the server already revealed an open port 443.
